# add date to the tablename on oracle using php

Tags: php, oracle

I'm trying to backup a table from oracle using php, and the table name should be `new table_20171221`. The date must insert current date when the table backup.

```
$date=date('Ymd');include("koneksi.php");
$query= 'CREATE TABLE new_table_`$date` AS SELECT * FROM old_table';
$statemen=oci_parse($c, $query);
oci_execute($statemen, OCI_DEFAULT);
oci_commit($c);
```

and the error messages :

> Warning: oci_execute(): ORA-00911: invalid character in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\import_excel_v\create_table.php on line 7

and is there any way that can insert a current date after `new_table`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the variable is not concatinated,

This should fix it

```
$query= 'CREATE TABLE new_table_'.$date.'AS SELECT * FROM old_table';
```

Comment: thanks... it is worked

Comment: Glad to be of any help!